# RW mounted NTFS drive not shown in finder

Tags: finder, external-disk, ntfs

I mounted my NTFS drive in OSX with

```
UUID=<some-uuid> none ntfs rw,auto,nobrowse
```

in fstab, but finder does not show the drive. I can do `open /Volumes/drivename` and will see the files and can even write on it. How can I force finder to show me the drive. (and the unmount icon)

Answer (score 2):

You should remove the `nobrowse` parameter because it tells the system that the mount point should not be visible via the GUI (i.e. on the Desktop).

Also, check your Finder preferences. In the "General" tab are options to show "Hard disks" and "External disks" on the desktop. In the "Sidebar" tab are similar options to show "Devices".

If this is an internal drive, the Finder will not show an "Eject" button, but you should be able to use Disk Utility to unmount.

Comment: Well it shows up, but the drive is mounted readonly without nobrowse. Any idea?

Comment: I dug around and found this: http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-57588773-263/how-to-manually-enable-ntfs-read-and-write-in-os-x/. Apparently `nobrowse` is needed in order to allow writing.